# php how to limit number of entry processes

Tags: php, memory, process, resources, limit

I have php website.
I continuosely get 508 resource limit exceeded error so am wodering how can I optimise my website to cope with it?

How for example I can lower the number of entry processes my scripts executes?

I already optimised my sql queries and simplified the code but it seems to be egtting worse than better.

Will be grateful for help.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried memcache.??

Comment: I think in that case you need to contact your server support person.

Comment: Have you very limited resources on  your host, or what script eat up that much memory? Check if mysql disconnects after every query, if so insted disconnect after all querys are done.

Comment: No, I did not try memchace will take a look how to use it. I'm on shared hosting so can't of course install anything there. I have limit of 20 entry processes. I have contacted my support they just advised me to upgrade to dedicated server which is not an option for me as this is several times more expensive than the current one. Anyway if there is something in my code/ mysql I'd prefer to optimise it than kill the server. How do I check mysql disconnects after every query? I use mysql_connect not mysql_pconnect

Comment: Have you managed to get this resolved? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

The "508 Resource Limit Is Reached" error message appears when an account exceeds the resources assigned to it  - CPU usage, RAM usage or the number of concurrent processes running under the cPanel account.

You can view the history of these limits being exceeded in cPanel, under Logs - Resources - Details.

There are several reasons that can be involved:
- Normal traffic. If your site experiences high peaks in normal traffic it can exceed allocated resources. If this is a regular occurrence we would recommend considering an upgrade to a Virtual Private Server, where no such limits are in place

- Problems in code. If there are pages on your site that have speed issues that have been introduced during development, a relatively small number of concurrent page requests can push the site over its resource limits
- Backend operations - demanding backend operations such as imports and exports can create significant load, which in addition to normal traffic can cause resource limits to be exceeded.
- Webcrawlers making a high number of requests per second. You can adjust the rate at which e.g. Google requests pages in Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: Thanks, I have found it in google but it doesn't say much how I can control it

Comment: Also, I know where to check my resource usage in cpanel. It just doesn't give me more than just stats

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your server/ account, with better resources.

Comment: it's not an option. I already did it anyway recently and it got worse not better